# Open a port CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, firewall

I'm new in CentOS and I'm trying to create a little script in Python, something like:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If I try to access port 8000 in my web browser, I don't get access, however if I turn off the firewall with:

```
$ system-config-firewall-tui
```

I'm able to access the service.

I just need to access port 3343 and 8880 but I don't want to disable the firewall.

Comment: So it works with the firewall off, but not when it's on?

Comment: Exactly! I think i need to configure the firewall to access only to this ports, but i dont know how :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3343 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: if IPTables are not running you may need to run "system-config-securitylevel" first. And if you want them to be permanent save them by running "/sbin/service iptables save"

Comment: @PurindaGunasekara - getting ahead of ourselves. If these rules solve the issue then yes, we can make these permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anybody who needs, after make the change in iptables i reload the services with:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

And

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```